# Sum of infinitely many integrals over a bounded interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Recalling from my days in Calc BC that if we have some integrable function $\ f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto f(x)$, three numbers $\ a,b,c \in \mathbb R,a \lt b \lt c$ and we know $\int_a^c f(x)\, dx=A$, then it follows that $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx +\int_b^c f(x)\, dx =A$, too. This always bothered me, because it seems like we're double counting at b.

To take the above property to its extreme, I wondered what would happen if we start dividing up the interval $[a,c]$ into smaller and smaller chunks and then summing up the integrals over said smaller and smaller chunks. In mathematical notation, I believe the above would be expressable as follows – define some $N \in \mathbb N$ and let $c-a=N\epsilon$, and take $$\displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty} \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \int_{a+j\epsilon}^{a+(j+1)\epsilon} f(x)\, dx.$$

My question is, can this above expression ever $\ne A$? If not, why does double counting a point on an integral an infinite number of times not affect its net value? As a follow up, what could happen if we let the various limits of integration overlap on some small interval larger than a point?

Thanks!

Comment: Intuition: points have zero width. So "double-counting" a _single_ point won't change your integral -- an integral is only sensitive to changes over intervals with positive width. 1/2

Comment: If you recall the definition of the integral of an integral function, and recall criteria allowing one to interchange two limits, I think you'll be able to show that the limit expression is equal to $A$ for any function $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$. 2/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible full answer to this question is to read a book on measure theoy and get a grip on the construction of the Lebesgue measure and the Lebesgue integral.

On a very informal level, the Lebesgue measure (on the real line) is an attemt to assign a *length* to as many subsets of the real line as possible. It starts from the basic assumption that an open interval $]a,b[$ should have length $b-a$. The further construction to measure the length of more complicated set is not so straightforward and I skip this. If you assume that the length of the set should be somehow continuous then what should be the length of the singleton $\{a\}$? Well $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0} ]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon[\ = \{a\}$ and thus, it should be $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 2\epsilon = 0$. Another important thing in measure theory is that the measure is (should be) *countably additive*, i.e., if you take the union of countable many disjoint sets, you can add up (i.e. take the limit of the series) the measures. <sup>(Note that this would not be a good property without "countably", as every set is the union of its elements, so union of set of length zero…)</sup>

Now, in your question, you count a countable number of points twice, so (still intuitively) you count a set of measure zero twice.

The Lebesgue integral is in fact quite similar to the Riemann integral - its main difference is that you divide the *range* of the function (and not the domain) which gives you an *adaptive* partition of the domain of the function. To be more precise, you approximate the integral of a positive function by discretizing the range by $0=y_0 < y_1 <\cdots y_n$ and taking
$$
\sum_i y_i\lambda(\{x\ :\ y_{i-1}<f(x)\leq y_i\})
$$
where $\lambda(A)$ is the (Lebesgue) measure of $A$. (Draw a sketch to convice yourself that this is indeed an approximation of the area under the curve.) An important consequence is, that changing a function on a set of measure zero, does not change its integral. So in your example, the (Lebesgue) integral of $f$ stays exactly the same if you set
$$
\tilde f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x = a+j\epsilon,\ j=0,1,\dots\\ f(x), & \text{else}\end{cases}.
$$
This new function $\tilde f$, has the same integral (area under the curve) but the values that you count twice are all zero…

A very short, intuitive answer: A point has zero length; coutalbly many points also have "zero total length", so counting them twice does not matter.

Comment: This is terrific - thanks for the measure theory primer!